# waitOn hook on Iron router for Subsciption: Images not loading

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

For my iron:router, I have a waitOn hook for subscription to a collection. Whenever I put the hook on, the page can't load the pictures from Public folder and I am not sure why that is.....

But whenever I remove the WaitOn hook, the picture loads again.

Subscription at Router

```
Router.route('/postPage/:_id', {
  name: 'profile',
  waitOn: function() {return Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id) ;},
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

Publication

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function(postId) {
  check(postId, String);
  return Comments.find({postId: postId});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason it could fail to load is that the `waitOn` is never returning. `waitOn` will block until all its subscriptions are all marked as ready by their respective publishers. In this case, the `comments` publisher would fail if `postId` isn't a string - an error will be thrown and `this.ready()` will never be called. I'd recommend debugging further by:

1. ensuring `this.params._id` is actually a string
2. temporarily removing `check(postId, String)` from the publisher

Comment: check(postId, String) is ensuring this.params._id is actually a string?? No?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - I mean you should just double check that you are actually sending a string - i.e. make sure `this.params._id` isn't `undefined`. Are there any errors showing up in either the terminal or in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

try `data: function() { return Posts.findOne(_id: this.params._id); }`